# Is it possible to use Javascript in Windows Service project?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, windows-services

I have a requirement where I need to generate Bing map control with push points (which is only doable using `JavaScript`) in a Windows Service.

**So my question is:**
Is it even possible to write `JavaScript` code in Windows Service project?

Comment: There are many, for example http://v8dotnet.codeplex.com/. But, running .js in your service code might not get you what you need. What do you want to do with this map after generating it?

Answer (score 1):

If you need an image of Bing Maps with pushpins on it then use the Bing Maps REST imagery service from inside your service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701721.aspx

Comment: Already looked in to it @rbrundritt but the problem with the static maps is that it only supports up to 100 pushpins. My dataset may have up to 300 geoloc values. However, I have a feeling that your blog is going to be useful to me. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this blog post on how to draw on the static image from the SOAP service (can easily be updated to use the REST imagery). http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2008/10/25/ve-imagery-service-and-custom-icons/

Comment: Thanks @rbrundritt. I will check that post.